# showing feed.mikle.com widget on https page

Tags: php, rss, feed

I am using feed.mikle.com widget to show google news on my page.

My google news url is https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=India

ANd the code given by feed.mikle.com is

```
    <!-- start feedwind code -->
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'https://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"><' + '/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "https://news.google.com/news/feeds?output=rss&q=India",rssmikle_frame_width: "300",rssmikle_frame_height: "400",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "13",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "on",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "off",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "20",sort: "New",rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "In the news",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#282929",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "150",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#B80404",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "325",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script><div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; "><a href="https://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a><!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div><!-- end feedwind code -->
```

My Problem is that my page is secure page (https) and the link and images given by the widget have http , [for example](http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNH-TqCE8fP-JvAc_5r6Mky5ZTrNEQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&ei=ZrojVPCTCc_9gAfGoYDgAg&url=http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/wireStory/india-successfully-puts-spacecraft-mars-orbit-25718475)

How can I make these urls secure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Content hosted on an HTTP-server are simply not encrypted on their way to the user. The holder of the content (in your case probably the newspapers providing the images) would need to place it on an HTTPS-server instead. You can't "convert" HTTP to HTTPS, or something similar, unless you would download all those images and host them on your server instead. But they would then still not be used, as Google's RSS feed wouldn't point to your server to load the images from.

Comment: A webserver can be configured to listen on both `HTTP` and `HTTPS`. Although you are correct that the `xml` would need some modification to work your approach on solving the problem is simply incorrect.